# Ionic IOS import more than one document

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, import, document

If I'm in the Apple Files App and select multiple documents and want to import them into my App it only imports the first document and not all of the selected documents. So when I start the simulator and open the finder I can see in the temp/Name-Inbox folder of the simulator that there is only one file, but I want to have all of them in this folder. Is there a setting I can change to make this possible for example in the Info.plist?

I'm Using Ionic 5 and Cordova 10.

This is my Info.plist:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en_US</string>
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>Name</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.1.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.1.0</string>
  <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
  <string/>
  <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
  <string/>
  <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
  <string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
  <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
  <true/>
  <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
  <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  </array>
  <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
  <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  </array>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
  <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  </array>
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app requires photo library access to function properly.</string>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app requires photo library access to function properly.</string>
  <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
  <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
  <false/>
  <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
  <false/>
  <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
  <false/>
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
          <array/>
          <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
          <array/>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>Portable Document Format</string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
          <string>Viewer</string>
          <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
          <string>Owner</string>
          <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
          <array>
              <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
          </array>
      </dict>
  </array>
  <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
  <array>
      <string>en</string>
      <string>de</string>
      <string>nl</string>
      <string>fr</string>
      <string>it</string>
      <string>pt-BR</string>
  </array>
  <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
  <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: If it is done for 1 file then that mean nothing can be done in setting, u need to check ur code ..

Comment: @MostafaHarb thanks for your answer. I already removed all the code in which I'm working with the file in the inbox folder, but there is still only the one file in my inbox. So whatever I change in my code is irrelevant, because I'm getting only the one file and not all of the files in the inbox folder. My code starts working after a file is added in the inbox, so the error can't be my code. The problem must be somewhere between the OS and the app communication.

Comment: What i mean is that if the device accepted one file, then there will be no problem with other files..that what i mean..